# GDB as default debugger

Tags: gdb

In Windows you can use a default debugger (gflag) that is called when a image name is run.
Can be this done with GDB and Linux? In Windows it's useful for debugging services.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this on Linux, short of hacking your kernel.

Nor is it usually necessary. If you always want to run e.g. `/foo/bar` under GDB, just do this:

```
mv /foo/bar /foo/bar.x
cat > /foo/bar <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
exec gdb --args /foo/bar.x "$@"
EOF
chmod +x /foo/bar
```

Problem solved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

yes, from the command line run:

```
gdb --args [program] [options]
```